# I need mysql regexp to get those records where resolution width is equal or more

Tags: php, mysql

Images Table

```
ID      IMG          Resolution
1       img1         1920x1080
2       img2         1366x768
3       img3         1366x768
4       img4         1920x1200
5       img4         1924x1200
```

I Want To Match Only Width In my case `[1920x1200] = [width x height]`
i want only those records where width is equal or more than 1920

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE resolution>= REGEXP{}";

In my case it should return only these records where resolution is greater or equal to 1920

```
ID      IMG          Resolution
1       img1         1920x1080
4       img4         1920x1200
5       img4         1924x1200
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should fix your data structure, so resolution is stored in two columns.  After all, it represents two *numbers*, not a string label.

You can do what you want, but not easily with a regular expression:

```
where substring_index(resolution, 'x', 1) + 0 >= 1920
```

This converts the first number to a number and then makes the comparison.